# How would I tell a bash script to start over from the top?

Tags: linux, bash, repeat

For example, in the below script `startover` starts back from the top:

```
##########################################################################
## CHECK TIME
##########################################################################
time=$(date +%k%M)

if [[ "$time" -ge 1800 ]] && [[ "$time" -le 2200 ]];then
echo "Not a good time to transcode video!" && exit 0
else
echo "Excellent time to transcode video!" && echo "Lets get started!"
fi
##########################################################################
## CHECK TIME
##########################################################################
startover
```

Also keeping in mind `exit 0` should be able to stop the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it in a while loop. I'd also suggest you add a "sleep" so that you're not racing your machine's CPU as fast as it will go:

```
while true; do
    ##########################################################################
    ## CHECK TIME
    ##########################################################################
    time=$(date +%k%M)

    if [[ "$time" -ge 1800 ]] && [[ "$time" -le 2200 ]]; then
        echo "Not a good time to transcode video!" && exit 0
    else
        echo "Excellent time to transcode video!" && echo "Lets get started!"
    fi
    ##########################################################################
    ## CHECK TIME
    ##########################################################################
    for i in {1..5}; do
        echo $i
        sleep 1
    done
done
```

Answer (score 11):

You could "recurse" using the following line:

```
exec bash "$0" "$@"
```

Since `$0` is the path to the current script, this line starts the script without creating a new process, meaning you don't need to worry about too many restarts overflowing the process table on your machine.

Comment: Might pass through `"$@"` so we don't lose arguments

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT USE WHILE LOOP at the start of the script since the condition below will exit the script and break the loop.

```
echo "Not a good time to transcode video!" && exit 0
```

You can try trapping the exit signal so that when the script exits it restarts

```
##########################################################################
## CHECK TIME
############bash##############################################################
trap '<path to script> ' EXIT
time=$(date +%k%M)

if [[ "$time" -ge 1800 ]] && [[ "$time" -le 2200 ]];then
echo "Not a good time to transcode video!" && exit 0
sleep 1;
else
echo "Excellent time to transcode video!" && echo "Lets get started!"
sleep 1;
fi
##########################################################################
## CHECK TIME
##########################################################################
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
echo 5
startover
```

Note: I add a sleep of 1 second because this will give you the time to see message. trap the exit signal and re-running the script is acting like a while loop. I am also assuming that these codes are in a script.

Comment: TO David Custer:
if you use a while do loop starting at the top of your script..your script will exit if it reaches the condition below:

echo "Not a good time to transcode video!" && exit 0
'
thereby breaking out of the loop and exiting script

Comment: Thank you for your help! I should have been more specific, that was my fault. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about enclosing the entire script in a `while` loop?  For example,

```
while :
do
    script
done
```

You may want to add a condition to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is not good practice, but what you asked for.

Put this at the end of your script. `"$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )/$(basename $0)"`

Comment: ./test.sh: line 17: /Users/username/Documents./test.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Good catch. Forgot to use the basename command on $0. Should work now.

Comment: If you don't use `exec` to replace the old instance with a new one in-place, then you're getting a continually-lengthening process chain when you do this. And what's the value added by the `dirname`/`basename` fuss, rather than just `exec "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"`?